# transforming URLS to active links with REGEX

Tags: regex

i have this code in php that transforms URL inside a text to active html links.

For example in a string

```
Hey check this cool link http://www.example.com
```

this transforms to:

`Hey check this cool link <a href="http://www.example.com">http://www.example.com</a>`

As you can see it just adds the correct < a > html tag

The code is this:

```
$active_links_text = ereg_replace("[[:alpha:]]+://[^<>[:space:]]+[[:alnum:]/]","<a href=\"\\0\">\\0</a>", $original_text);
```

My question is, how to do this to work EXCEPT if the URL is a youtube url.

So i want this result: In a string

```
Wow have you checked http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ its even better than http://www.example.com !!!
```

i want to be transformed to

```
Wow have you checked http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ its even better than <a href="http://www.example.com">http://www.example.com</a>
```

As you can see the < a > html tag was added to the example.com's URL but NOT at the youtube's URL.

How can i make this happen???

I hope i described my problem good enough, i hope its easy to implement this! Last note: i am using this code in php 5.2.14

Thank you guys!

Comment: I think, you should construct to URL property, to match the `http` URL, as described in the [spec](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt). Particularly, your regex doesn't match `?`. Also, there may be `&`, `#`...

Comment: On a sidenote, the ereg_* functions are deprecated in php 5.3. You may want to use preg_* already.

Answer (score 0):

[EDIT : Wow, I had gotten your question completely wrong! Below's a better attempt at helping you.]

I gave it a go in js [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Piflechien/uJLh5/2/), here is the original regex : `/(http:\/\/(?!www.youtube)[^<>\s]+)\b/g`, since i'm not a php coder. The negative lookahead prevents a litteral www.youtube match (the lookahead content can be adapted if you need a more complex pattern).

There's nothing js-specific here to my knowledge, but I don't know the *ereg* regex syntax. with preg functions, you would just need not to escape the slashes, the word boundaries `\b` and negative lookahead `(?!*pattern*)` are the same. The `/g` flag is for a global replacement, that is, not stopping on the first match, I suppose you have a kind of replaceAll function in your toolbox.

Also, I'm not sure about the global flag in php, I guess you can just call a kind of replaceAll function.

Answer (score 0):

You've made several mistakes about valid URI components. The scheme is defined as [ALPHA *( ALPHA / DIGIT / "+" / "-" / "." )](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.1), not `[[:alpha:]]+`.

The part after the `:` of the scheme need not start with `//`, that's particular to `http:` and a few other file-oriented schemes. But the `[[:alpha:]]+:` start of your regex shows you weren't aiming to restrict yourself to `http:`. In that case, all printable ASCII characters are valid. I.e. everything from `!` to `~`, or `[\x21-x7E]*` as a regex.

To summarize: `[[:alpha:]][A-Za-z0-9+-.]*:[\x21-x7E]*`.